# Cannot sort custom linked list

Tags: sorting, linked-list

Basiclly, I created a custom linked list class which

```
public class LList<T> implements ListInterface<T>{
```

however when I try to sort the custom linked list, I get error, no suitable constructor found.
This is the error

```
no suitable method found for sort(ListInterface<Patient>)
method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
    (argument mismatch; ListInterface<Patient> cannot be converted to List<T#1>))
method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
  T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
  T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
```

This is how I sort the patient list

```
ListInterface<Patient> patientList = new LList<>();
Collections.sort(patientList);
```

this is orverride method in patient class

```
    @Override
public int compareTo(Patient t) {
    int patientSeriouness = t.seriousness;
    Date arrival = t.date;
    if (this.seriousness == patientSeriouness) {
        return this.date.compareTo(arrival);
    } else {
        return Integer.compare(this.seriousness, patientSeriouness);
    }
}
```

What my problem actually? Thank you for teaching.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort()` API is available for parameter List type and not ListInterface and hence its not compiling. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) for details.

Comment: So is there any way to sort my ListInterface?

Comment: You will have to manually write sort logic, just like what Collections.sort does.